# Al instalar Spark y Hadoop en google colaboratory no se puede encontrar py4j, a causa de SPARK_HOME?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-colab, jvm, hadoop

Quiero utilisar PySpark en Google Colab. Entonces sigué [este tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/pyspark-in-google-colab-6821c2faf41c). Utilicé la versiones de spark y hadoop las mas recientes:

```
!apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk-headless -qq > /dev/null
!wget -q https://downloads.apache.org/spark/spark-3.1.1/spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz
!tar -xvf spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz
```

Que me devuelve:

```
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/NOTICE
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/kubernetes/
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/kubernetes/tests/
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/kubernetes/tests/python_executable_check.py
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/kubernetes/tests/autoscale.py
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/kubernetes/tests/worker_memory_check.py
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/kubernetes/tests/py_container_checks.py
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/kubernetes/tests/decommissioning.py
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/kubernetes/tests/pyfiles.py
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/kubernetes/tests/decommissioning_cleanup.py
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/kubernetes/dockerfiles/
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/kubernetes/dockerfiles/spark/
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/kubernetes/dockerfiles/spark/decom.sh
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/kubernetes/dockerfiles/spark/entrypoint.sh
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/kubernetes/dockerfiles/spark/bindings/
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/kubernetes/dockerfiles/spark/bindings/R/
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/kubernetes/dockerfiles/spark/bindings/R/Dockerfile
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/kubernetes/dockerfiles/spark/bindings/python/
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/kubernetes/dockerfiles/spark/bindings/python/Dockerfile
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/kubernetes/dockerfiles/spark/Dockerfile
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/RoaringBitmap-0.9.0.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/hive-vector-code-gen-2.3.7.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/guice-servlet-4.0.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/kerb-crypto-1.0.1.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/kerby-asn1-1.0.1.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/derby-10.12.1.1.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/hadoop-annotations-3.2.0.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-3.2.0.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/commons-beanutils-1.9.4.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/okhttp-3.12.12.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/httpcore-4.4.12.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/logging-interceptor-3.12.12.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/scala-library-2.12.10.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/spark-mllib-local_2.12-3.1.1.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/parquet-format-2.4.0.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/kerb-identity-1.0.1.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/kryo-shaded-4.0.2.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/commons-compiler-3.0.16.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/jdo-api-3.0.1.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/spire-macros_2.12-0.17.0-M1.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/json4s-core_2.12-3.7.0-M5.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/JLargeArrays-1.5.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/jsp-api-2.1.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-3.2.0.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/kubernetes-model-autoscaling-4.12.0.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.30.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/json4s-ast_2.12-3.7.0-M5.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/hive-cli-2.3.7.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/parquet-common-1.10.1.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/json-smart-2.3.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/stax-api-1.0.1.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.10.0.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/hive-storage-api-2.7.2.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/algebra_2.12-2.0.0-M2.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/spire-util_2.12-0.17.0-M1.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/jline-2.14.6.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/breeze_2.12-1.0.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/metrics-jvm-4.1.1.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/dropwizard-metrics-hadoop-metrics2-reporter-0.1.2.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/machinist_2.12-0.6.8.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/scala-compiler-2.12.10.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/commons-pool-1.5.4.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/spark-network-shuffle_2.12-3.1.1.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/token-provider-1.0.1.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/spark-repl_2.12-3.1.1.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/jta-1.1.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/kubernetes-model-admissionregistration-4.12.0.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.8.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/metrics-graphite-4.1.1.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/spark-streaming_2.12-3.1.1.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/spark-launcher_2.12-3.1.1.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/objenesis-2.6.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/kerby-pkix-1.0.1.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/jpam-1.1.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/kubernetes-model-common-4.12.0.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/kubernetes-model-extensions-4.12.0.jar
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/py4j-0.10.9.jar
...
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/mypy.ini
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/pylintrc
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/MANIFEST.in
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/README.md
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/test_coverage/
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/test_coverage/coverage_daemon.py
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/test_coverage/conf/
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/test_coverage/conf/spark-defaults.conf
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/test_coverage/sitecustomize.py
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/run-tests.py
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/setup.py
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/test_support/
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/test_support/userlibrary.py
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/test_support/hello/
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/test_support/hello/sub_hello/
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/test_support/hello/sub_hello/sub_hello.txt
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/test_support/hello/hello.txt
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/test_support/userlib-0.1.zip
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/test_support/SimpleHTTPServer.py
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/test_support/sql/
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/test_support/sql/people.json
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/test_support/sql/people_array.json
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/test_support/sql/people_array_utf16le.json
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/test_support/sql/text-test.txt
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/test_support/sql/ages.csv
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/test_support/sql/parquet_partitioned/
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/test_support/sql/parquet_partitioned/year=2015/
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/test_support/sql/parquet_partitioned/year=2015/month=10/
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/test_support/sql/parquet_partitioned/year=2015/month=10/day=26/
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/test_support/sql/parquet_partitioned/year=2015/month=10/day=26/.part-r-00005.gz.parquet.crc
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/test_support/sql/parquet_partitioned/year=2015/month=10/day=26/part-r-00005.gz.parquet
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/test_support/sql/parquet_partitioned/year=2015/month=10/day=25/
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/test_support/sql/parquet_partitioned/year=2015/month=10/day=25/.part-r-00002.gz.parquet.crc
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/test_support/sql/parquet_partitioned/year=2015/month=10/day=25/.part-r-00004.gz.parquet.crc
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/test_support/sql/parquet_partitioned/year=2015/month=10/day=25/part-r-00004.gz.parquet
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/test_support/sql/parquet_partitioned/year=2015/month=10/day=25/part-r-00002.gz.parquet
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/test_support/sql/parquet_partitioned/year=2015/month=9/
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/test_support/sql/parquet_partitioned/year=2015/month=9/day=1/
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/test_support/sql/parquet_partitioned/year=2015/month=9/day=1/.part-r-00007.gz.parquet.crc
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/test_support/sql/parquet_partitioned/year=2015/month=9/day=1/part-r-00007.gz.parquet
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/test_support/sql/parquet_partitioned/_metadata
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/test_support/sql/parquet_partitioned/year=2014/
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/test_support/sql/parquet_partitioned/year=2014/month=9/
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/test_support/sql/parquet_partitioned/year=2014/month=9/day=1/
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/test_support/sql/parquet_partitioned/year=2014/month=9/day=1/.part-r-00008.gz.parquet.crc
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/test_support/sql/parquet_partitioned/year=2014/month=9/day=1/part-r-00008.gz.parquet
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/test_support/sql/parquet_partitioned/_common_metadata
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/test_support/sql/parquet_partitioned/_SUCCESS
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/test_support/sql/orc_partitioned/
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/test_support/sql/orc_partitioned/b=1/
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/test_support/sql/orc_partitioned/b=1/c=1/
...
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/licenses/LICENSE-jaxb-runtime.txt
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/licenses/LICENSE-minlog.txt
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/licenses/LICENSE-mustache.txt
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/licenses/LICENSE-xmlenc.txt
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/licenses/LICENSE-jline.txt
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/licenses/LICENSE-istack-commons-runtime.txt
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/licenses/LICENSE-py4j.txt
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/licenses/LICENSE-vis-timeline.txt
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/licenses/LICENSE-re2j.txt
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/licenses/LICENSE-kryo.txt
spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/licenses/LICENSE-cloudpickle.txt
```

Luego installé `findspark` con `!pip install -q findspark`.

Y ahora que hemos instalado Spark y Java en Colab, es el momento de establecer la ruta de entorno que nos permita ejecutar PySpark en nuestro entorno Colab. Establece la ubicación de Java y Spark ejecutando el siguiente código:

```
import os
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "/content/spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz"
```

Pero cuando intenté ejecutar una sesión local de Spark para probar nuestra instalación:

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
```

Me parece que hay problemas, no se puede encontrar `py4j`:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/findspark.py in init(spark_home, python_path, edit_rc, edit_profile)
    142     try:
--> 143         py4j = glob(os.path.join(spark_python, "lib", "py4j-*.zip"))[0]
    144     except IndexError:

IndexError: list index out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/findspark.py in init(spark_home, python_path, edit_rc, edit_profile)
    144     except IndexError:
    145         raise Exception(
--> 146             "Unable to find py4j, your SPARK_HOME may not be configured correctly"
    147         )
    148     sys.path[:0] = [spark_python, py4j]

Exception: Unable to find py4j, your SPARK_HOME may not be configured correctly
```

Answer (score 1):

Analizando el error veo el problema esta en la variable`os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "/content/spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz"` estas apuntando al paquete `.tgz` cuando tienes que apuntas al directorio que descomprimiste `os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "/content/spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2`

Te dejos los pasos para descomprimir el archivo por si no lo has hecho:

```
wget -q https://downloads.apache.org/spark/spark-3.1.1/spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz
tar -xvf spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz
```

Answer (score 0):

No sé si te servirá, pero yo hice lo siguiente:

```
!apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk-headless -qq > /dev/null
!wget -q https://downloads.apache.org/spark/spark-3.1.1/spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz
!tar -xvf spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz
!pip install -q findspark
```

```
import os
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "/content/spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2"
```

```
import findspark
findspark.init()

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
```

Todo esto fue realizado en Google Colab

Comment: por favor explica un poco mas tu código, esto ayudara a las personas a entenderlo y aprender